# Missing { inserted <to be read again>

Tags: errors

I have looked through the code on the line specified time after time and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

> ```
> "! Missing { inserted.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \endgroup 
> l.204 ...\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n sin\frac_{n\pi x}
>                                                   {L}e^{-k(n\pi/L)^2 t}"
> ```

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
        u(x,t) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n cos\frac{n\pi x}{L} e^{-k(n\pi/L$
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\frac` doesn't use `_`; it's just `\frac{n \pi x}{L}`. you're also missing a brace after `...e^{...$`

Comment: unrelated to the error but never use `cos` and `sin` always `\cos` and `\sin`

Comment: Thank you, it was the _ after frac that was causing the issue!

Comment: Also, @David what is the reason for using \cos or \sin? the regular sin and cos seem to work just fine.

Comment: @Javier look at the output! math italic is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word, they are widely separated, as adjacent letters in math are usually multiplication of separate variables. `sin` typesets the same as `s i n` with the font trying to make it clear this is the three variables s i n not the word sin.  `\sin` uses a roman font and gives the construct the correct spacing for a prefix operator.

Comment: Note that your example code did not have `_` after `\frac` so would not have produced the error shown. Also it is not on line 204. Please always make examples complete (with `\documentclass`) and check they generate the error that you are asking about.

Comment: The reason the example code did not show the _ after \frac is because there was a second summation term after the $. This is where the _ appears after the \frac and was shown in the error message.

Comment: Yes but that is not useful, it is far better to make a complete example document and _show the error generated by that document_ In this case you were lucky and Sean spotted it but the example code was no help at all, rather the opposite as it did not contain the error. That can not happen if you always only post the error generated by the posted example.

Comment: This really need a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @SeanAllred Close as unclear, or do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Since there's no MWE, the question lends itself more to closing as unclear – unfortunately there's been no appropriate update from OP. Thanks though!

Comment: As I said earlier, this was the issue: Thank you, it was the _ after frac that was causing the issue!